# In a linux kernel module, how can I get inode of a known path

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, inode

In a linux **kernel module** (i.e. working in kernel space), I have a path of a file.

Which function(s) can be used to get the inode of that file. Specifically I need to get the "inode *" pointing to the file's inode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to open the file. There is a lookup function available in kernel which translates `char *name` to `struct nameidata`. Please refer to [path_lookup](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.31/fs/namei.c#L1093).

You may also want to take a look at how path resolution algorithm works, [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filp_open` function, but as stated in the comment of the function, opening files in kernel module is not something you want to do.

Here is a [function](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.31/fs/namei.c#L1912) that will return the `struct file` for your path. From there I think you can go to the inode

Bonus : May be this is not what you intend to do, but here is [an article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110) on file reading / writing from the kernel, and why you don't want to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the warnings but I do not intend to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience with kernel, I suggest that you always go for top level functions like path_lookup rather than functions in the middle.